# Future perfect continous vs Future perfect tense

Tags: tense, future-perfect, perfect-continuous, future-constructions

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> My aunt **will have been living** in England for five years when I go there.

and

> My aunt **will have lived** in England for five years when I go there.

Answer (score -1):

This question appears quite regularly.

There are answers [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31897/dilemma-present-perfect-or-perfect-continuous) that may be useful.

[This](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/future-continuous-and-future-perfect) British Council's page may also help.

Comment: Continuous also emphasises that it is continuing into the time being discussed. Future perfect simple can indicate something that has completed in the future (by the time under discussion). Pragmatics come into it - if you're talking about visiting and someone living there, then the listener assumes they are there when you visit - but something like "I will have studied Russian for five years when I go there" doesn't imply you are still studying.

Comment: @Stuart F: Seven months ago I referred the OP to a similar question where, among other answers, mok's was useful. It has since vanished. I'll edit my answer.